# ¿Por qué los elementos generados automáticamente no escuchan eventos? JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de creación de facturas y quiero dar al usuario la posibilidad de crear filas dinámicamente.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  nRows = 0;
  $("#addRow").click(function(){
    nRows ++;
    idRow = "row"+nRows;
    console.log(idRow);
    $(".array").append('<div class="row" id="'+idRow+'"><input class="producto" type="text" placeholder="Producto" value=""><select class="tipo-unidad" name=""><option value="Hr">Horas</option><option value="Ud">Unidades</option><option value="Kg">Kilos</option></select><input class="precio" type="text" placeholder="Precio" value="0"><input class="cantidad" type="text" placeholder="Cantidad" value="0"><span class="total">0</span><a class="removeRow" href="#">-</a></div>');
    selectors();
  });
}
```

y, también quiero que el usuario pueda eliminar dichas filas. He probado esto, pero solo funciona con la primera fila (creada estáticamente con HTML):

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Saludos, creo que esto atiende tu problema [Delegando eventos en jquery a elementos dinamicos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/161235/157535)

Comment: @Josbert lo que tú propones ya lo había probado antes (con poca suerte jeje), pero gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si bien, en comentarios te sugieren una buena opción, no responde el título de tu pregunta

> ¿Por qué los elementos generados automáticamente no escuchan eventos?

Porque al usar `$(selector)`, jQuery analiza el DOM y obtiene solo los elementos existentes.

**Solución:** Delegar el evento, es decir, escuchar clics en otro contenedor y que jQuery analice si el evento fue disparado por un elemento específico, ya sea por etiqueta, clase, id, etc.; así, la función se va a ejecutar solo cuando el clic sea en un elemento que coincida con el selector, sin importar si existía al crear la función o se agregó posteriormente.

En tu caso, sugiero delegar el evento al contenedor `.array`, que es donde agregas los nuevos elementos y usar la clase del enlace `.removeRow`. De esta forma, evitas que el navegador analice cada clic en todo el documento y aseguras que aplique solo a los enlaces deseados.

Adicionalmente, usa el método [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) para acceder al padre y eliminar toda la fila.

```
$('.array').on('click', '.removeRow', function() {
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Funciona de maravilla :)