# Barra de progreso no capta datos que se generan dinámicamente

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

He creado campos dinámicos, surge lo siguiente:
Tengo una barra de progreso que se genera dinámico, pero no capta el progreso al dar clic en botón de mas de la barra.
**El siguiente código capta el id de progress**

```
    $(document).on( 'click', '.btn-aumentar_dina', function(){

      $('.progress-button_dina').each( (index, element) => {
        lable = document.getElementById("lable");
       progrees = $(element).attr('id');
       console.log(progrees);

       var lable = document.getElementById("lable");
       document.getElementById("pluss").onclick = function(){
        
        console.log(progrees.value);
         if(progrees.value < 100){ 
            progrees.value += 10; 
           lable.innerHTML = "Valor: "+progrees.value;
        }else if(progrees.value==100){ 
            alert("No se puede sobrepasar!");
         }

     };
      });
    });
```

En el código que muestro arriba puedo obtener el id del progress que se ha generado dinámicamente, el detalle pasa cuando hago lo siguiente: console.log(progrees.value); es para acceder al value.

```
'<progress id="campoBenf5'+contador+'" name="campoBenef[]" 
  value="0" max="100" class="progress-button_dina" indeterminate 
  required></progress>'+
'<div id="lable">Valor: 0</div>'+
'<input type="button" id="minuss" value="-" class="btn-reducir" 
  name="beneficiario[]">'+
'<input type="button" id="pluss" value="+" class="btn-aumentar_dina" name="beneficiario[]">'+
```

**el código de arriba es de la barra de progress, el value tiene como valor 0 y quiero hacer un console.log como lo ya mencionado console.log(progrees.value); pero me dice undefined.**

Espero me entiendan y agradezco el apoyo.

Comment: Estás asignando los eventos solo a elementos existentes, pero no a los que agregas posteriormente. Revisa [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/467375/54039), seguro te ayuda a resolver el problema.

Comment: Ok amigo, ahorita chocaré esa gran aportación. De antemano te agradezco el tiempo para darme tu apoyo

Comment: @Triby disculpa, ya estoy obteniendo el id así var progrees = $(element).attr('id'); solo que cuando quiero acceder al value de esta forma progrees.value me dice undefined. y no se a que se deba.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para poner tu código actualizado.

Comment: @Triby hermano no se si te referías a modificar la publicación, pues ya lo hice no sé si ahora me doy a entender. Gracias. Nota: soy nuevo aquí..