# ToggleClass no funciona cuando agrego un li a mi lista mediante append

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Estoy haciendo un To Do List en Javascript con Jquery.
El proceso de capturar el input del usuario y crear un nuevo li item (append) al ul funciona, pero al intentar darle un toggleClass a los nuevos li, estos no funcionan.

Si creo los li individualmente en html, el toggle class si funciona.

Cual sería el problema?

En index.js

```
function createNewItems() {
  for (i = 0; i < toDoItems.length; i++) {
    var newLi =
      "<li>" +
      "<span class='dot'><svg class='check' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='11' height='9'><pathfill='none'stroke='#FFF'stroke-width='2'd='M1 4.304L3.696 7l6-6'/></svg></span>" +
      "<h4>" +
      toDoItems[i] +
      "</h4>" +
      "<svg class='cross' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'width='18' height='18'><path fill='#494C6B' fill-rule='evenodd' d='M16.97 0l.708.707L9.546 8.84l8.132 8.132-.707.707-8.132-8.132-8.132 8.132L0 197l8.132-8.132L0 .707.707 0 8.84 8.132 16.971 0z'></path></svg>" +
      "</li>";

    $("#myUl").append(newLi);
  }
}
```

```
En styles.js
```

````
$(".dot").click(function () {
      $(this).children("svg").toggleClass("asd");
      $(this).toggleClass("checked");
      $(this).parent().toggleClass("crossed");
    });

    $("li").on("mouseenter", function () {
      $(this).children(".cross").css("z-index", "1000");
    });
    $("li").on("mouseleave", function () {
      $(this).children(".cross").css("z-index", "-1000");
    });
    $(".cross").click(function () {
      $(this).parent().remove();
    }); ```
````

Comment: En [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/467375/54039) se trata el mismo problema: Los eventos aplican solo a elementos existentes y no a los que se agregan posteriormente. La respuesta te será muy útil.

Answer (score 0):

si funciona el detalle es que sobrescribes lo que ya tienes dentro.

pero puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
function createNewItems() {
// creamos la variables
var newLi ="";
  for (i = 0; i < toDoItems.length; i++) {
// concataneamos el string
     newLi +=
      "<li>" +
      "<span class='dot'><svg class='check' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='11' height='9'><pathfill='none'stroke='#FFF'stroke-width='2'd='M1 4.304L3.696 7l6-6'/></svg></span>" +
      "<h4>" +
      toDoItems[i] +
      "</h4>" +
      "<svg class='cross' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'width='18' height='18'><path fill='#494C6B' fill-rule='evenodd' d='M16.97 0l.708.707L9.546 8.84l8.132 8.132-.707.707-8.132-8.132-8.132 8.132L0 197l8.132-8.132L0 .707.707 0 8.84 8.132 16.971 0z'></path></svg>" +
      "</li>";

    
  }
 // al finalizar agregamos
  $("#myUl").append(newLi);
}
var toDoItems =[1,2,3,4,5,6];
createNewItems();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myUl">

</ul>
```