# Utilizar JQuery en otro nivel del DOM despues de ser llamado por una funcion PHP y Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estoy desarrollando un formulario para diligenciar una hoja de vida en php, jquery. en la cual hay una sección de estudios, en ella hay un botón de agregar mas estudios que al realizar un click en el aparece un contenedor que permite diligenciar la información del nuevo estudio. En esta hay un input select en donde hay una opción de universidad al seleccionar la opción de otra universidad debe de aparecer un campo que dice cual y así poder escribir la universidad del aspirante.

Este es el HTML del boton agregar Estudio

```
<span class="mcf-formulario__boton mcf_letraBoton" id="mcf_formulario_agregarEstudio" >Agregar estudio</span>
```

Esta funcion es la que se llama con Ajax para que aparesca cuando se haga click en el boton

```
  function mcf_ajaxAgregarCamposEstudio(){
    if( isset( $_POST['contador'] ) && !empty( $_POST['contador'] )  ):
      $i = $_POST['contador'];
      ?>
      <div class="mcf_cont_estudios mcf-formulario__cont_ajax" id="mcf-formulario__cont_ajax_<?php echo $i;?>">
        <div class="mcf-formulario__cont">
          <div class="mcf-formulario__cont-input mcf-formulario__cont--1campo" id="mcf-formulario__cont-input">
                <select name="mcf_universidad[]" id="mcf-formulario__input_universidad_<?php echo $i;?>" class="mcf-formulario__input mcf_letraCampos mcf-form_selectU">
                    <option value="0">Seleccionar</option>
                    <?php 
                        global $wpdb;
                        $tabla = $wpdb->prefix.'universidades'; 
                        $results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM '.$tabla.' ', OBJECT );
                        foreach($results as $r):
                          ?><option value="<?php echo $r->id;?>"><?php echo $r->nombre;?></option><?php
                        endforeach;
                    ?>
                    <option value="-1">Otra universidad</option>
                </select>
                <label  class="mcf_letraLabel mcf-formulario__label"
                        id="mcf-formulario__input_universidad_9" 
                        for="mcf-formulario__input_universidad_9" >
                        Universidad<span class="mcf-formulario__asterisco">*</span></label>     
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mcf-formulario__cont mcf_cont_otros mcf-ocultar" id="mcf_cont_otros_<?php echo $i;?>">
            <div class="mcf-formulario__cont-input mcf-formulario__cont--1campo" id="mcf-formulario__cont-input">
                <input  type="text" 
                        class="mcf-formulario__input mcf_letraCampos " 
                        id="mcf-formulario__input_otra_universidad_9"
                        name="mcf_otra_universidad[]"
                        value=""
                        />
                <label  class="mcf_letraLabel mcf-formulario__label"
                        id="mcf-formulario__label_otra_universidad_9" 
                        for="mcf-formulario__input_otra_universidad_9" >
                        ¿Cuál?<span class="mcf-formulario__asterisco">*</span></label>      
            </div>
        </div>
       
      </div>
      <?php
        wp_die();
    endif;
  }
```

Esta es la funcion en JS que realizaria el evento cuando hago click en el campo select.
*Nota: en este caso solo tengo especificado que me seleccione el primer contenedor que aparezca despues de haber pulsado el boton de agregar estudio.*

```
 function mostrarOtraUniversidadEnOtrosEstudios(){
            $(document).on("click",'#mcf-formulario__input_universidad_1', function( event ){
                alert('FUNCIONO')
            });
    }
    
    mostrarOtraUniversidadEnOtrosEstudios();
```

El inconveniente que tengo actualmente, es que al realizar click o mas bien un evento que genere o llame un bloque de HTML y PHP llamado desde Ajax por medio de JQuery no trabaja el Jquery en el DOM de este nuevo nivel. En este caso al hacer click en el input Select creado después oprimir el boton no aparece un alert que diga FUNCIONO

Comment: ¿Que id tiene el contenedor donde insertaras ese contenido que recibes desde ajax?

Comment: Un problema es que estás usando IDs dinámicos y tendrías que crear una función para cada formulario o selector. Lo más adecuado es usar clases y te recomiendo leer [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/467375/54039). Si los ID se repiten, definitivamente te va a funcionar solo con el primero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una posible solución que tienes es probar de usar la delegación de eventos en javascript para conseguir que los eventos esten disponibles en el nuevo HTML que ha sido agregado mediante ajax.

Para ello debes predefinir en el código javascript inicial el evento a tratar, asignándolo o bien al immediato contenedor donde se alojará ese nuevo HTML o bien a alguno superior.  De este modo, y gracias a la delegación/propagación de eventos de javascript, podrás capturar los eventos sobre el nuevo HTML y realizar las acciones que convenga.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que el nuevo HTML va a estar dentro de este contenedor:

```
<div id="contenedor_respuesta_ajax"></div>
```

Y que quieres controlar, tal como propones en tu pregunta, el evento `click` sobre el nuevo id (traído desde ajax) que según parece en tu código lo generas dinámicamente agregando un número al final, y que empezará por la cadena `mcf-formulario__input_universidad`.

Lo que debes hacer es dejarlo preparado así desde la carga inicial de la página:

Otra edición con soporte para todos los `id` que empiecen por la cadena `mcf-formulario__input_universidad` (gracias al último y más preciso aporte de **@Triby**):

```javascript
$('#contenedor_respuesta_ajax').on("click",'[id^=mcf-formulario__input_universidad]', function(){
  alert('FUNCIONO')
});
```

Anterior edición (gracias al aporte de @Triby en comentarios)

```javascript
$('#contenedor_respuesta_ajax').on("click",'#mcf-formulario__input_universidad_1', function(){
  alert('FUNCIONO')
});
```

Anterior respuesta:

```javascript
$(document).on("click",'#contenedor_respuesta_ajax', function(){
  if (event.target.id == 'mcf-formulario__input_universidad_1') {
    alert('FUNCIONO')
  }
});
```

Prueba a ver si así te funciona.

Aquí te dejo un snippet para que lo veas en funcionamiento, pero sin ajax, para que te hagas a la idea:

```js
$('#contenedor_respuesta_ajax').on("click",'[id^=mcf-formulario__input_universidad]', function(){
  alert('FUNCIONO')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contenedor_respuesta_ajax">
  <p>
    Si pulsas aquí no funciona
  </p>
  <div id="mcf-formulario__input_universidad_1">
    Aquí sí que funciona (id terminado en _1)
  </div>
  <div id="mcf-formulario__input_universidad_2">
    Aquí también (id terminado en _2)
  </div>
  <div id="mcf-formulario__input_universidad_33">
    Y aquí (id terminado en _33)
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery te permite delegar directamente los eventos. Según la [documentación](https://api.jquery.com/on/) solo se necesita: `$('#id-padre').on('click', '.clase-hijo', function() { /* Código aquí */});` y no hay necesidad de filtrar internamente. Por supuesto, `#id-padre` y `.clase-hijo` pueden ser cualquier selector CSS válido, ID, clase, etiqueta, atributo, etc.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias! acabo de actualizar mi respuesta con tu aporte

Comment: Perdón por interferir, pero viendo que usa IDs dinámicos, terminando con `_1`, `_2`, etc. Un selector para el hijo podría ser `[id=^"mcf-formulario__input_universidad"]` que es una expresión regular para indicar que al inicio del ID debe contener ese texto y el final puede ser variable. Referencia [respuesta SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23223564/2412893).

Comment: @Triby Ale, he reeditado la respuesta de nuevo con tu último aporte.  Este me ha costado un rato más porque me habias puesto comillas dentro de los corchetes y me daba errores y no encontraba la sintaxis correcta :-)  Gracias!  Así da gusto aprender

Comment: Ups, me equivoqué, es que el formato es `[id^="cadena-inicial"]`, el circunflejo va antes del signo igual. ¡Sorry! xD

Comment: Pues ahora que lo dices, yo todo el rato pensaba que era por las comillas y no entendia porque me seguia dando errores, hasta que finalmente lo he copiado de tu enlace y sin comillas, y seguramente, sin darme cuenta, me habian cambiado el circunflejo de lugar, je... en fin... te perdono, **pero me lo apunto** (lo se, es una forma de perdonar muy falsa :-D)