# no funciona el llamado a otra ventana o función al avanzar la paginación en php

Tags: javascript, php, html

tengo un inconveniente al hacer click en el boton "Acción" de una tabla, tengo un paginador que muestra los primeros 10 lineas de la tabla y el boton "acción">>"ver"  o  "acción">>"eliminar" no funciona al pasar a la pagina 2 en adelante o si muestro mas registros solo funciona en los primeros 10 registros de la tabla.
Agrego el codigo PHP que hace la llamada a una funcion en javascript

***CODIGO PHP***

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" style="">
<a class="dropdown-item view_user" href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">Ver</a>
<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="./index.php?page=edit_user&id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">Editar</a>
<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
<a class="dropdown-item delete_user" href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">Eliminar</a>
</div>
```

***CODIGO JAVASCRIPT***

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#list').dataTable()
    $('.view_user').click(function(){
        uni_modal("<i class='fa fa-id-card'></i> Detalles de Usuario","view_user.php?id="+$(this).attr('data-id'))
    })
    $('.delete_user').click(function(){
    _conf("¿Estás segur@ de eliminar a este usuario?","delete_user",[$(this).attr('data-id')])
    })
    })
    function delete_user($id){
        start_load()
        $.ajax({
            url:'ajax.php?action=delete_user',
            method:'POST',
            data:{id:$id},
            success:function(resp){
                if(resp==1){
                    alert_toast("Datos eliminados correctamente",'success')
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        location.reload()
                    },1500)

                }
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

***CODIGO COMPLETO***
https://github.com/pakis1081/phpcode.git

***agradezco su ayuda***

Comment: consejo git es para compartir código y no para cargar comprimidos, así es difícil ayudar, cuando plantees un problema piensa que la otra parte (nosotros) no tenemos idea de como funciona el código o sistema, realiza preguntas explicando y dando mas contexto del problema. muchas veces el explicar con claridad el problema ayuda a solucionarlo mas fácilmente.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/467375/por-qu%c3%a9-los-elementos-generados-autom%c3%a1ticamente-no-escuchan-eventos-jquery/467382#467382) para saber porqué los eventos no aplican a elementos agregados dinámicamente y cómo delegarlos.

Comment: gracias, lo tendré en cuenta